# redirecting to 2 pages 50% at the time in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, redirect, load

I am trying to redirect on loading the page but i want it to be 50% of the time , to page1.php and 50% to page2.php

Any idea how can I write it in PHP? do I store it in an Array or how could I do that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Several ideas, what have you tried already so we don't waste your time getting you to try it again?

Comment: `if (rand(0, 1)) header('Location: page1.php'); else header('Location: page2.php');`

Comment: I didnt try anything yet, i dont know where to start

Comment: i dont think this will be 50% of the time??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pretty short script. Use the built-in PHP function `mt_rand($min, $max)`.

```
if (mt_rand(0,1) == 0) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/redirect1/');
    exit;
} else {
    header('Location: http://example.com/redirect2/');
    exit;
}
```

Or as a ternary, which can be a little less readable if not using variables:

```
header(mt_rand(0,1) == 0 ? 'Location: http://example.com/redirect1/' : 'Location: http://example.com/redirect2/');
exit;
```

Or using variables:

```
$redirect1 = 'http://example.com/redirect1/';
$redirect2 = 'http://example.com/redirect2/';
header('Location: ' . mt_rand(0,1) == 0 ? $redirect1 : $redirect2);
exit;
```

Comment: but will that load 50% even if users check the page at the same time?

Comment: From a human standpoint, the likelihood of two users hitting the same page on the same microsecond is very low and even if it does occur, will even out over time. I'll update my answer with `mt_rand` though, as it produces a better random number. -edit-someone beat me to it.

Comment: rand is not that random, better to use mt_rand, also it will never be pure 50% of the time unless the value is stored.

Comment: Thank you Loz. Here is the docs page for it if others are curious: http://us3.php.net/mt_rand

Comment: so if i want to have 50% i need to store 0 or 1 in a database and keep updating those as the pages load ?

Comment: No, this alone suffices.